# Ruby on rails: Avoid drop down if values are already selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby on rails. I have one query

I have one view (say view1) in which I am showing a drop down. For that I have passed and array and populating the drop down using that array like dis

```
<td><=% select_tag, options_for_select(@businessApprovers)></td>
```

So when I submit the form it goes to an action which intrun renders another view which has 5 tabs in body and each tab has a partial view. one of them calls my previous view view1. Now when it calls the view1 it again shows the drop down. instead it should show only one value and that too non editable.

we are having some other drop down too but they have hard coded values. We are doing that like this:

```
<td><=% f.field :contries, :condition_select, [abc,pqr] ....
```

and above thing is working fine. For that it is not showing drop down.
So I wanted to know how to avoid that drop down. Also what is the use of "f.field" because I removed that and from then on it is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, field is for CSV, text_field is a thing. Is that what that should be? Also, I'm hoping that's not exact code.

Instead of:

```
<td><=% f...
```

It should be:

```
<td><%= f...
```

That aside, if you're simply looking to display a select field when no selection has yet been made and simply text when it DOES have a value, then it would be as simple as using a conditional:

```
<% if thing.something.empty? %>
  <%= f.select ... %>
<% else %>
  <%= thing.something %>
<% end %>
```

If my assumptions were incorrect, please reply and I'll revise.